# In VS Code, is it possible to hide markdown text such as &emsp; from the outline in the explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This might be a long shot, but I will ask anyway.

I have a jupyter notebook in VS code. This notebook consists of markdown and code. The outline panel acts as a table of contents for my markdown.

One problem I encounter is that I use `&emsp;` at the beginning of some markdown headers to create spacing. Is it possible to have the outline ignore such spacing arguments and just show the actual text?

For example, I have the markdown syntax `### &emsp; Heading text`

Comment: I bit unclear with where exactly you're putting it. Before or after the `#` characters? Show a [mre]?

Comment: Perhaps report it as a bug? I would expect those characters to not show up in Outline.

Comment: I don't think it is a bug, but more a feature request. Where would I request such a thing?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode